# How to register notifications from parse for sound and alerts? (in Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using parse notifications, but I want the notification to give an alert and a sound. I now have this:

```
 var pushSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)
```

But how do I also register for .sound? In objective-C it's apparently this:

```
 // Let device know you're going to be sending one of these types of notifications.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

But, I am very new to Swift and I really don't know how to use it in Swift!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
let pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: nil)
```